# Get size of specific repository in Nexus 3

Tags: nexus, nexus3

How can I get a size of specific repository in Nexus 3?

For example, Artifactory shows the repository "size on disk" via UI.

Does Nexus have something similar? If not - how can I get this information by script?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use admin task with groovy script nx-blob-repo-space-report.groovy from https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-14837 - for me turned out too slow

Or you can get it from database:

1. login with user-owner nexus installation on nexus server (e.g.
   nexus)
2. go to application directory (e.g. /opt/nexus):

   `$ cd /opt/nexus`
3. run java orient console:

   `$ java -jar ./lib/support/nexus-orient-console.jar`
4. connect to local database (e.g. /opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/component):

   `> CONNECT PLOCAL:/opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/component admin admin`
5. find out repository row id in @RID column by repository_name value:

   `> select * from bucket limit 50;`
6. get sum for all assets with repo row id found in the previous step:

   `> select sum(size) from asset where bucket = #15:9;`

result should be like (apparently in bytes):
`+----+------------+
 |#   |sum         |
 +----+------------+
 |0   |224981921470|
 +----+------------+`

nexus database connection steps took from https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002930827-Accessing-the-OrientDB-Console

#### another useful queries

summary size by repository name (instead 5 and 6 steps):

```
> select sum(size) from asset where bucket.repository_name = 'releases';
```

top 10 repositories by size:

```
> select bucket.repository_name as repository,sum(size) as bytes from asset group by bucket.repository_name order by bytes desc limit 10;
```

Comment: If you are using the Docker image (sonatype/nexus3), after you connect to the running Docker container (`sudo docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/sh`) then the jar executable is: `java -jar /opt/sonatype/nexus/lib/support/nexus-orient-console.jar` and then the connection command after this connects is `> CONNECT PLOCAL:/nexus-data/db/component admin admin`

Comment: I don't have the nexus-orient-console.jar on my server, I'm using version OSS 3.15.2-01, is that a feature for the Enterprise version?

Comment: it should be there even on OSS version (I got 3.15.1 and also had it on previous versions too).

Comment: How can we check further sizes under releases repository? i mean size of each release?

Comment: Don't skip point 1 - it renders nexus unable to access the database!
To correct this mishap run (assuming nexus as your service user) `chown -R nexus:nexus /opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/db`

Answer (score 10):

Assign each repository to its own Blob Store.

[image]

Comment: This is a very good tip for new repositories (and I upvote it), but it doesn't help with existing repos.

Comment: gotta know that layers are not shared between blob stores, so in your quest to analyze disk space, you may very well end up doubling disk usage :)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below GitHub project. The script can be help to clear storage space on Nexus repository by analyzing the stats generated by the script. The script feature prompt-based user input, Search/Filter the results, Generates CSV output file and Print the output on console in a tabular format.

[Nexus Space Utilization - GitHub](https://github.com/shamsher-ansari/nxrm-space-utilization)

You may also refer below post on the same.

[Nexus Space Utilization - Post](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/shamsher-ansari-0a056a16a_nexus-repository-manager-activity-6967465798349017088-u20H?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop)