# nexus3 size used by repositories does not match database size on disk

Tags: nexus3

I'm analyzing the disk usage of our **nexus3** instance. I used [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816723/get-size-of-specific-repository-in-nexus-3) to get the disk space used by all repositories:

```
cd /opt/nexus
java -jar ./lib/support/nexus-orient-console.jar
> CONNECT PLOCAL:/opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/component admin admin
> select bucket.repository_name as repository,sum(size) as bytes from asset group by bucket.repository_name order by bytes desc;
```

Then by summing all results I get approximately **200GiB**. When I move around on the disk however, I get a disk usage of **378BiB**:

```
> du -sh /opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/blobs
378G     blobs/
```

Where does this difference come from? Is this normal, or are there some manipulations I could or should do to clean this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently artifacts are not removed from disk when deleted in the interface. Therefor one needs to run the **Compact Blob Store** task. After running this task, my disk usage is 180G.