# In nexus3 how can I find out what consumes space in a blobstore (apart from the sum of assets)?

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I have a question quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816723/get-size-of-specific-repository-in-nexus-3) on a more abstract level:

Via API I get a blobstore size (`totalSizeInBytes`) and a left free space value (`availableSpaceInBytes`) of resulting in roughly 566gb of *used* space.

Iterating over all repositories and summing up sizes of all assets gives me only 478gb giving me a missing 88gb.

While used space in general doesn't have to be equal to the sum of sizes of all content elements 15% seems to be a lot to me. Is there a way to know what consumes the rest of the used space? Maybe dangling elements?

Answer (score 1):

On Nexus, when you remove some artifacts, not the whole disk space would be freed, for performance reasons.

In order to get the "missing space" be reclaimed you should instrument the blob store compact tasks, like mine:

[image: Compact blob store]